# How to set channels and sample rate when converting .wav into mp3 using NAudio/Lame?

Tags: naudio, lame

I am trying to convert wav file into mp3 using following code.

```
using (var wavRdr = new WaveFileReader(item))
                using (var mp3Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(outputPath.Replace(".wav", ".mp3"), wavRdr.WaveFormat, _bitRate, tag))
                {
                    wavRdr.CopyTo(mp3Writer);
                }
```

LameMP3FileWriter does not have any parameter to set **Channels** and **Sample Rate** for MP3 format.

After some research, i have got an idea that i have to set the channel and sample rate before calling the conversion method but i do not know how to do this.

I used [this](https://github.com/Corey-M/NAudio.Lame) for conversion which i have done successfully but now i need to set channels and sample rate for mp3 file. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have solved the problem.

```
var tempFile = Path.Combine(destFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFile.SourceFilePath) + ".wav");
            try
            {
                var reader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFile.SourceFilePath);
                var newFormat = new WaveFormat(SampleRate, BitsPerSec, Channels);
                var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(newFormat, reader);
                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(tempFile, conversionStream);

                var destFile = Path.Combine(destFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFile.DestiFileName) + ".mp3");
                using (var wavRdr = new WaveFileReader(tempFile))
                {
                    using (var mp3Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(destFile, newFormat, BitRate, sourceFile))
                    {
                        wavRdr.CopyTo(mp3Writer);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Ignore
            }
            finally
            {
                if (File.Exists(tempFile))
                    File.Delete(tempFile);
            }
```